# getting the group name as a list after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by

I am using python groupby function to group using two columns

```
grouped =df.groupby(['col2','col4']).size().groupby(level=0).size()
```

I got the output

```
col2
item1            1
item2            1
item3            7
item4            6
item5            3
item6            5
```

I want the list of group names with size>3 as below:

```
['item3','item4',item6]
```

Trying the code

```
list(grouped)
```

gives me the list of number but not the list of group names required. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Filter index values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = grouped.index[grouped > 3].tolist()
```

Alternative:

```
out = grouped[grouped > 3].index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[*grouped.loc[lambda x: x > 3].index]
```

or

```
[*grouped[grouped > 3].index]
```